WooCommerce Bookings - Last day of booking available for the next customer
My customer runs a pet hotel. Customer can choose, whether they bring their dog for half-day, full-day or multiple days. Same rooms are used for half-days and full days.
WooCommerce Bookings product works for this very well, except the next customer should be able to choose the last day of the other customers booking. Eg. Room 1 has been booked for 1.2.-3.2. New customer should be able to book it starting from 3.2. (Preferably by choosing time as well.) I have not found a way to do this.
Is this possible? Accommodations plugin brought up a whole new set of problems, booking product have only this one problem.

You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is off topic here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
